# Fillfactor recommendation for index on UUID column in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

**Background**

I have a new table in a PostgreSQL 9.4 database with a UUID primary key. This table collects information for 1 week and then is archived on AWS S3 and deletes it. It will insert an average of 40K-50K records per day. There are virtually never any updates to the table or UUID primary key. I have no ability to change this table's primary key type.  The UUIDs generated and used as the primary keys are version 4 (random).

**Question**

If disk space is not my primary concern and I want to optimize for inserts, what fillfactor should I be using for this index. I know the default is 90%, but my hunch is that a number around 50 would help increase the throughput on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created 7 different tables with 1 uniquely indexed uuid column. The I used fillfactors of 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 (the default). Then I inserted 1,000,000 records into the table (using `uuid_generate_v4()`). There was no significant difference in the times.